# Add to cart Button on home not upgrading the cart

Tags: magento-1.8, checkout, addtocart

I am having an strange problem i have attached new product at home page by calling the block template at home page under `CMS->page->home` but when click on add to cart button it will redirect to `www.example.com/checkout/cart` but show's the message cart is empty.
but when i go to any category and try to add product from there. It will work properly and after that when i again click on add to cart of home page it workes.  The file called new.phtml which i am using to call the block has the following code

```
<?php if (($_products = $this->getProductCollection()) && $_products->getSize()): ?>
<div class="page-title category-title">
        <h1><?php echo $this->__('New Products') ?></h1>
</div>
<?php $_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount(); ?>
    <?php $i=0; foreach ($_products->getItems() as $_product): ?>
        <?php if ($i++%$_columnCount==0): ?>
        <ul class="products-grid row">
        <?php endif ?>
            <li class="item col-xs-3<?php if(($i-1)%$_columnCount==0): ?> first<?php elseif($i%$_columnCount==0): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">
                <div class="product-container">
                <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(188) ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>" /></a>
                <div class="product-shop">
                    <h3 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?></a></h3>
                   <!--  <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short') ?> -->
                    <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true, '-new') ?>
                    <div class="actions">
                        <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                            <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
                        <?php else: ?>
                            <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Details') ?>" class="button btn-details" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Details') ?></span></span></button>
                        <!-- <ul class="add-to-links">
                            <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                                <li><a href="<?php echo $this->getAddToWishlistUrl($_product) ?>" class="link-wishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php if ($_compareUrl = $this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product)): ?>
                                <li><span class="separator">|</span> <a href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>" class="link-compare"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?></a></li>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </ul> -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId()); ?>
                <div class="label-product">             
                    <?php if($_product->getData('new')){echo '<span class="new">'.$this->__('New').'</span>';  }?>
                    <?php if($_product->getData('sale')){echo '<span class="sale">'.$this->__('Sale').'</span>';  }?>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
            </li>
        <?php if ($i%$_columnCount==0 || $i==count($_products)): ?>
        </ul>
        <?php endif ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

so can any one help me were i am wrong my website is http://www.royalcandycompany.com/

Comment: jquery conflict issue solve first then check ajax return value for conformation popup.

Answer (score 1):

Please try using the below code for "Add to Cart" button.

```
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/product_compare')->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>', true)"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
```

The above code has been tested and it worked for me on my home page.

Let me know if you find any issues with the above code.

Thanks.